# How is primary defined for FL2015-3L?

Tags: transformer, inductance

The FL2015-3L transformer has a datasheet (https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/6651db01-d153-47d9-8a27-4758c28bff0d/fl.pdf), which says its inductance is 19uH with a note that it is measured across both halves of the primary. I assume this means each half has an inductance of 19uH/4=4.75uH. Do you read this the same way?

And if they say the primary:secodary turns ratio is 1:100, do I interpret it correctly that primary means across the two halves? That is, if I am correct, the output inductance is 190mH?

I would appreciate it if you could indicate in your answer whether you have experience with this particular transformer or you just make a conclusion based on the datasheet.

Comment: One should be careful about assumptions of primary inductance, particularily if used as a Royer circuit with saturating inductance.  But centre tap means half of the primary relative to the tap and half the primary indutance. But if used in resonant linear mode then non-saturating with sine waves.

Comment: At the end of the day, you should still measure it. That’s what I do most times to ensure I didn’t have a dumb moment :)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 as explained to you in a link I gave you lower down, LT = (L1 + L2 + 2M) and, in this situation (L1 and L2 being strongly coupled and the same value), M = L1 = L2. Therefore LT = L1 + L1 +2L1. Hence LT = 4 x L1 (or L2). Or, put another way, inductance is proportional to \$N^2\$ (when a decent core is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I assume this means each half has an inductance of 19uH/4=4.75uH. Do
> you read this the same way?*

I read it the same way. Each half primary has an inductance that is a quarter of the full primary.

> *And if they say the primary:secodary turns ratio is 1:100, do I
> interpret it correctly that primary means across the two halves? That
> is, if I am correct, the output inductance is 190mH?*

I read it as the full 19 μH is transformed via \$N^2\$ to a secondary inductance of 190 mH (as you have).

My answer is based on experience of wound components and the datasheet information.

Comment: [Have you heard of mutual inductance?](https://www.electronicshub.org/inductors-in-series/#:~:text=When%20two%20or%20more%20inductors,called%20%E2%80%9CMutually%20connected%20inductors%E2%80%9D.)

Comment: Right TY for reminding me and Ltotal = L1+L2+2*sqrt(L1*L2)